# Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, java-time

I am pretty new to Java 8 time, so this question probably has an obvious answer but after reading the other similar SO questions I couldn't spot any similarities which cause my issue.

Here's my class:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocalDateTimeIssue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "18-04-2019 12:14:46";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString , dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt.getSecond());
    }

}
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18-04-2019 12:14:46' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=14, HourOfAmPm=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=46},ISO resolved to 2019-04-18 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at LocalDateTimeIssue.main(LocalDateTimeIssue.java:10)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=14, HourOfAmPm=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=46},ISO resolved to 2019-04-18 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=14, HourOfAmPm=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=46},ISO resolved to 2019-04-18 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has to be `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

```
 h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
 H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
```

Because in your example, the 12 can either be AM or PM.

---

The formatter cannot decide between AM or PM as the information is missing:

```
 a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
```

Both are possible, thus the error `Unable to obtain LocalTime` occurs.